# ngrok always deleted the cookie i sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, ngrok

I'm using `ngrok http 5173` to expose my React app online. However, when I set a cookie in the ngrok-app from my Express server using the following code:

```js
res.cookie("myCookie", "value", { secure: true, sameSite: 'None', maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 });
```

The cookie gets deleted every time the browser is refreshed or directed to another route.
tested in localhost is working normally

Comment: Is ngrok a reverse proxy, if so have you done -> `app.enable('trust proxy')` on your express app.

Comment: @Keith tried that, and it makes my front-end page doesn't receive any cookie from express app.